# Displaying full integers instead of scientific notiation when printing out Vaex HDF5 data

Tags: python, output, vaex

my code:

```
myfile = vaex.open('myfile.hdf5')
myfile['customer_id']
```

output:

```
 Length: 4,259,376 dtype: int64 (column)
  0   9.4618e+08
  1  9.43324e+08
  2  9.43325e+08
  3  9.43333e+08
  4  9.43333e+08
    ...
```

How can I change the output format to normal like:

```
  Length: 4,259,376 dtype: int64 (column)
  0   946832204
  1   943662763
  2   943724406
  3   943725670
  4   943334500
    ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look up "Python output format".  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @Prune, thank you for first comment. I know pd.set_option can do if I use pandas, but I don't know how to do with Vaex. If you know it, please let me know, that will save a lot time for me. Thanks!

Comment: Use standard Python formatting and keep the resulting string.
Print that string as your output.

Comment: @Prune, thank you! I did convert to string and all looked fine. Just want to know if want integer, is there a way to change such output by using Vaex?

Comment: You would answer that question using the [vaex documentation](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html).    I would find it strange to have such a package re-implement formatting that already exists in the parent language.